# Testng does not count dataprovider tests individually

Tags: java, testng, testng-dataprovider

Here is my dataprovider

```
@DataProvider(name = "arrayBuilder")
public Object[][] parameterTestProvider() {
    //Code to obtain retailerIDList
    String[] retailerIDArray = retailerIDList.toArray(new String[retailerIDList.size()]);
assertEquals(1295, retailerIDList.size(), "Expected 1295, found " + retailerIDList.size() + " docs");
    return new Object[][] {{retailerIDArray}};
}
```

and this is my test

```
@Test(dataProvider = "arrayBuilder", invocationCount = 1, threadPoolSize = 1)
public void getRetailer(String[] retailerIDList) {

    for (String retailer_ID : retailerIDList) {
        //Code that uses the retailerID 
 }
```

When I execute this test, TestNG output lists "getRetailer" as the only test. I have 1295 records returned by dataprovider and I want 1295 tests to be reported. What am I missing?

Comment: Has it run the method 1295 times for each row of data ? if not then your data provider implementation is incorrect. If it has run that many times then it would have provided results for each test data set used. Please look carefully in the report.

Comment: I put debug messages within the test and I can see each of the 1295 values printed correctly. DataProvider is working well except that TestNG reports it as a single test.

Comment: Which report are you looking at. In both the reports emailable-report.html and index.html in the test results folder i  can see separate rows for each row of data provider without doing any thing extra. Can you tell me which report you are looking at.

Comment: index.html lists this as a single test.

Comment: Of course it will.. You are sending it one single  data which is an array and then looping it. That is not the way data provider works. You need to send it each element as each row.... Wait i will try to give an example implementation of DP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this, it should work. You need to return array of objects where each row is a row of data that you want to use for a test. Then only it will come in the report. What you were doing was sending it an array so it was treating it as a single test.

```
    @DataProvider(name="provideData")
    public  Iterator<Object[]> provideData() throws Exception
    {
        List<Object[]> data = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
        String[] retailerIDArray = retailerIDList.toArray(new String[retailerIDList.size()]);
        assertEquals(1295, retailerIDList.size(), "Expected 1295, found " + retailerIDList.size() + " docs");
        for(String retailerID : retailerIDArray ){

            data.add(new Object[]{retailerID});

        }

        return data.iterator(); 

    }

@Test(dataProvider = "provideData")
public void getRetailer(String retailerIDList) {

    for (String retailer_ID : retailerIDList) {
        //Code that uses the retailerID 
    }
}
```

For more Information please go through the documentation [here](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders)

Comment: @Test(dataProvider = "provideData")
    public void getRetailer(String retailerID) {

       //Code to work directly on each element of the iteration, i.e. retailerID
    }   Thanks, the double array is unnecessary and a bit confusing imho.

Comment: Welcome. Yes its not required in your case. I copied it from my implementation where it is required as there  are multiple parameters. Can you please accept it as answer if it has worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

DataProviders alone, while iterating for each data set, will only yield a cumulative result for the test instead of a result for each iteration.

Try using a Test Factory alongside the DataProvider for an individual result for each iteration of the test.

http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#factories